# Restore system disk to a larger drive failed to boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, backup, partitioning, restore

I used DriveImage XML to backup a 40GB IDE system disk (Windows XP) and restore it to a blank 80GB IDE. After the restoration, I switched the IDE cables and made sure the system will boot to the 80GB but I got boot failure error after POST.

Note that when I used EaseUS DiskCopy on same set of disks to do the same thing, it works. I was able to boot the 80GB disk. My only problem with EaseUS DiskCopy is it divided my 80GB to 40GB/40GB.

My question now is:

1. What's the problem with the DriveImage XML method and how can I fix it?
2. For the EaseUS DiskCopy, how can I maintain 80GB partition when copying a 40GB disk?

BTW, if it means anything, the system disk that I backed-up is active and it's where DriveImage XML is running.

Comment: Just a parition program to combine the two paritions. If this was Windows 7 you would have the ability to use the built in Disk Mangement program to do so.  I suspect the error is caused by DriveImage XML I suggest you use a better program.

Comment: You probably won't be able to.  So you'll have to partition it 40/40.